# Java: should I use "this" keyword or "m_" prefix?

Tags: java, instance-variables

To refer to instance variables, should I use the "this" keyword...

```
class Foo
{
    private int bar;

    public Foo(int bar)
    {
    this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

OR the "m_" prefix (Hungarian naming convention where m means "member variable")...

```
class Foo
{
    private int m_bar;

    public Foo(int bar)
    {
    m_bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Are there any situations where one provides an advantage over the other?

Comment: You should use `this`, as it's actually Java style and Java syntax.

Comment: There are two *different* questions going on here - both are subjective. 1) I don't use `m_`, 2) I use `this` when and only when it is required.

Comment: @user2864740 OP seems to be proposing the use of "m_" when `this` would be required. I believe the consensus thus far is don't do that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I can your point .. but such seems a silly proposal.

Comment: I'd personally just go `public Foo (int inBar) { bar = inBar }`.  Is this frowned upon?

Comment: I picked prefixing with `m`, not `m_` (that's just bad c++ looking stuff IMO), from Android. I actually like it, but only do it there. Prefixing helps, in some cases, your code be more descriptive, for example `sDataStore` letting "everyone" know it's a singleton.

Comment: @redFIVE possibly, it's a lot more readable to just use `this.bar = bar`. I see people that use the different variable names are more often than not beginners or people who don't drop the habit. But over time I've moved to *always* referencing class methods and fields internally with `this`.

Comment: @Rogue: auto-complete works nicely in that regard as well. Otherwise you'll have to make changes to generated code to match what you have.

Comment: Robert Martin's "Clean Code" (in a part written by Tim Ottinger) recommends not using prefixes: "You also don’t need to prefix member variables with m_ anymore. Your classes and functions should be small enough that you don’t need them."  I use `m` in Android programs because it's the Android coding standard, but I don't like it.

Comment: Programming style questions like these are almost always off topic for being *primarily opinion based*. However this question *is* on topic because 1) Java has a well established conventional style, ultimately derived from the original Sun style guide 2) Hungarian notation is so widely condemned that it would be accurate to say there was a consensus.

Comment: Unfortunately,  although not off topic for being primarily opinion based, this is really 2 separate questions, and thus *too broad*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` is standard, more readable, and less error prone.

It will help you when you are mistakenly shadowing variables or and trying to access non-static field in static code.

i.e to avoid this

```
int m_bar;
public Foo(int m_bar)
{
  m_bar = m_bar;
}
```

and
    static int m_bar;

```
int m_bar;
public Foo(int bar)
{
  this.bar = m_bar; // a warning static field being accessed as non-static
}
```

Comment: I disagree - but such is a subjective question/answer. I *only* use `this` where it is required (and `m_` not at all). My IDE (go JetBrains!) tells me when it's "wrong".

Comment: you shouldn't stay dependent on IDE's error protection

Comment: I agree with this answer as the example given by the user is a clear case where disambiguation is required. "m_" does not follow the general standard of camel-case variable names and "this" is the general standard used.

Comment: @kharyam The fact that both cases appear is confusing and results in a poor question - and thus I disagree with the initial proposal. `this` is required sometimes, but not others. `m_` is merely a convention. Two different [subjective] cases.

Comment: @user2864740 However, the use of a backing field named the same as the property is nearly universal Java usage. You might as well say it's subjective to start Java class names with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @kharyam: yes, `m_` doesn't follow camel-casing but the Android practice of `m` like `mBar` does. Using underscore separators in Java is just plain sacrilege.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify what you mean by the second part, i.e. what does it mean to "shadow" variables, and what does it mean to "try to access non-static field in static code"?

Comment: @Niko I updated with examples

Answer (score 2):

Use `this`. It is Java syntax that is provided for exactly this usage and developers are familiar with it and helps reduce syntax errors in several corner cases.

A possible issue with prefixing field names in Java is that the tools for generating getters and setters won't work as well. Additionally, some Java Bean tools like Jackson or GSON will now require mappings to map your object field names. Finally, as it isn't following Java style or convention the [maintenance developer](http://tiernok.com/blogPosts.php?article=be-mindful-with-your-code) will not be pleased.